# Подгрузка изображений в ListView с сервера

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

Подскажите, пожалуйста, с подгрузкой пользовательского изображения в `ListView`.

Я просто не так давно занимаюсь разработкой Android, не могли бы вы мне помочь с объединением?

```
chatAva = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViews);

    String[] texts = { "sometext 1", "sometext 2", "sometext 3",
            "sometext 4", "sometext 5" };

    data = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>(
            texts.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < texts.length; i++) {
        map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        Picasso.with(this).load(url).into(chatAva);

        map.put(LV_TEXT, texts[i]);
        map.put(LV_IMAGE, img);
        data.add(map);
    }

    String[] from = { LV_TEXT};
    int[] to = { R.id.textView2};

    sAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, data, R.layout.tab_left_list, from, to);
    sList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvChat);
    sList.setAdapter(sAdapter);

}



public class MyAdapter extends SimpleAdapter{

    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to){
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        // here you let SimpleAdapter built the view normally.
        View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        // Then we get reference for Picasso
        ImageView img = (ImageView) v.getTag();
        if(img == null){
            img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageViews);
            v.setTag(img); // <<< THIS LINE !!!!
        }
        // get the url from the data you passed to the `Map`
        String url = (String) ((Map)getItem(position)).get(LV_IMAGE);
        // do Picasso
        Picasso.with(v.getContext()).load(url).into(chatAva);

        // return the view
        return v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Реализуйте свой адаптер, наследующий `BaseAdapter` и в методе `getView` как раз и подгружайте картинки для нужной `ImageView` в каждой ячейке `ListView`